# Create Vim Command for a Regex search

Tags: regex, search, vim, xvim

I have a few Regex expressions that I use with xVim for Xcode.  Rather than repeatedly typing them out in the command bar with `\<Regex>`, I'd like to be able to invoke them with a custom command, like `:Regex1`.  So I've added `command Regex1 “/-\s*\(“` to my `xvimrc` file and restarted Xcode.  When I run `:Regex1` however nothing happens.

Comment: What makes you think anything should happen?

Comment: Maybe that wasn't clear.  What I want to happen is for that regex to be entered as a Vim search.  Subsequently, stepping through the results with `n`, `N` should jump to each match.  So when I type `:Regex1` I expected that to be equivalent to `/-\s*\(`.

Comment: Again what makes you think anything should happen? Do you see `:command` [in that file](https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim/blob/master/Documents/Users/FeatureList.md)? xVim is **not** Vim so there's no reason whatsoever to expect any Vim thing to work as-is in xVim.

Comment: I'm confused. The command I have the expectation for is `:Regex1`, which from my understanding is a custom command defined in the `xvimrc` file.  xVim supports a `xvimrc` config file so I guessed that custom commands would be an included feature.

Comment: The more thorough you are at reading the documentation of your tools the less confused you are.

Comment: I think `:command` is a vim extension, that is not available in other vi clones (xvim)

Answer (score 1):

Your command wouldn't even work in original Vim. I don't know xVim, but try something along these lines:

```
" With cursor moving to match.
command Foo /foo/

" Just updating the search pattern (but less likely to be portable to xVim).
command Foo let @/ = 'foo'
```

If none of that works; try defining a *mapping* instead. As this is just translating keys, it has the highest chance of being supported.

Comment: so i have `command Foo /-\s*\(` in my vimrc file, but when i type `:Foo` in my editor, i don't feel like it is working.  if I type `n` or `N` the cursor does not move to the matching text.  am i missing a step?

Comment: That particular command yields `E54: Unmatched \(` for me. Change `\(` to `(` to make it work.

Comment: Perhaps we are experience different results based on the environment.  I'm doing this in `xvim` which I assumed supports custom commands.  When I add `command Foo /-\s*(` to my `xvimrc` file, then type `:Foo` in the editor and hit Enter, the bottom bar clears text (the command was entered..).  And then using `n` or `N` does not jump to the expected Regex matches.  In my case I'm trying to match against method signature's such as `-(void)` or `- (void)` which is why I had a backslash before the `(` to escape that, so i believe my original Regex was correct.  Tho the command mechanism is failing

Comment: Does xVim have a `:help` that documents what is supported (or any limitations, or change in syntax compared to Vim)? It looks like this isn't supported. Maybe you'll get better results with a mapping...

Comment: Sure.  I'll look into a mapping.  My assumption was that, given my pathetic Vim comprehension, it was almost definitely something I was doing incorrectly.  I mentioned xVim as my environment to provide context.  So I'm feeling now like the problem is pointing towards xVim not supporting custom commands?  I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using this PERL Regex plugin since it already does what you want.

https://github.com/othree/eregex.vim

Answer (score 1):

**Abbreviations ...**

I understand you often use the same regex. You can use abreviations instead of a command to do a search.

```
ab re -\s*(
```

then type <kbd>/</kbd> + <kbd>re</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> and your long regex (here just "-\s*(" should expand).

**... Not user defined command**

User defined commands are not available in ed nor in vi nor in vim without the +eval compilation flag (`:h user-commands` and scroll one line up).

For a list of ex commands: http://www.csb.yale.edu/userguides/wordprocess/vi-summary.html

For a list of ed commands: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/ed.html